# pandas split columns using length

Tags: python, pandas

How to split columns in pandas using length.  `str.split` needs to use a delimiter . I could use slicing twice on each column like below

```
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
   df[f'mn{i}'] = df[col].str.split[1:]
   df[col] = df[col].str.split[:1]
```

So looking for more efficient like an inbuilt function in pandas which could split many columns based on length.

Dataframe

```
Col1     Col2      Col3
012021   012021    032021
012021   012021    032021
```

Expected output

```
Col1     Col2      Col3   Col4     Col5      Col6
01       01        03     2021     2021      2021
01       01        03     2021     2021      2021
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `str.extract` and `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df[x].str.extract('(\d{2})(\d{4})').add_prefix(f'{x}_') 
           for x in df], 
          axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Col1_0 Col1_1 Col2_0 Col2_1 Col3_0 Col3_1
0     01   2021     01   2021     03   2021
1     01   2021     01   2021     03   2021
```

Comment: So `str.extract('(\d{2})(\d{4})') ` creates 2 columns based on `(\d{2})` and `(\d{4})` ?

Comment: @sjd yes, the pattern has two capture groups, each would be a new column.